# How can I change the radius of a curve based on the distance to another object?

Tags: geometry-nodes

After changes in Geometry Nodes and new fields philosophy I'm feeling confused. How to access and modify attributes not exposed as fields as for example modifying the radius of curve basing on distance to other object?

[image]

Like on the image above, after *Mesh to Curve* object has attribute *Radius* that can be set using *Set Curve Radius* but I would like to set radius 1 only inside of the sphere and keep it at 0 otherwise. So I would like to extract this attribute, edit it and set again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's cool, thanks for help! But I'm still not sure about this attributes, how can I add new custom attribute and use it in the graph? It's common case in Houdini when you creating some help or teporary attributes.

Comment: Glad I could help. I don’t know Houdini, sorry. I think there are no custom attributes at all. Just the „built in“- ones. But i might be wrong....i am still learner of the fields thing... ;)

Comment: You need to use the capture attribute node https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong. Thanks Gorgious, learnt again 

Comment: Wow…didn’t even know we have now a good documentation of geometry nodes with examples!!! GREAT

Comment: @vklidu: although i am not Gorgious ;) ...i have tried the example of the docu. Works for me. Maybe you want to try my setup? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZR2G.jpg -> and now it works in eevee and cycles. I know that in the old GN it worked only for cycles

Comment: @vklidu: do you have the latest gn? here is the blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Qn6jwk6m" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Qn6jwk6m/) it looks a bit different, but it works

Comment: ... one week matters :) sorry ... your file works. Manual version of node tree needs "Set Material" node now too. I'm going to delete all my unrelated comments here. Thank you for help :)

Comment: You are welcome